# SQL Server: get all rows where ProductID occurs

Tags: sql-server

Given this data set:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | ProductID | quantity |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |        4 |
|  1 |         2 |       13 |
|  1 |         4 |       12 |
|  1 |        19 |        3 |
|  2 |        19 |        4 |
|  2 |        22 |        2 |
|  2 |         2 |        6 |
|  2 |        38 |        1 |
|  2 |        14 |        4 |
|  3 |        11 |        5 |
|  3 |        12 |        6 |
|  4 |        13 |        3 |
|  4 |        14 |       11 |
|  5 |        15 |        2 |
|  6 |        16 |        3 |
|  7 |        17 |        4 |
|  8 |        18 |        9 |
|  8 |        19 |        8 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

and my result set should look like this:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | ProductID | quantity |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |        4 |
|  1 |         2 |       13 |
|  1 |         4 |       12 |
|  1 |        19 |        3 |
|  2 |        19 |        4 |
|  2 |        22 |        2 |
|  2 |         2 |        6 |
|  2 |        38 |        1 |
|  2 |        14 |        4 |
|  8 |        18 |        9 |
|  8 |        19 |        8 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

I'm trying to look up the ProductID 19 and my result set must contain all IDs, Product IDs and quantities.

How does this work? I tried different types of subqueries and JOINS but I couldn't manage this.

Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server 2018

Data Schema: 
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVNig.png)

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 in the works - take your pick.....

Answer (score 1):

it seems you need just `in`

```
select t.ID ,t.ProductID,t.quantity 
from your_table t where t.ID in ( select ID from your_table t1 where t1.PRODUCT_ID =19)
```

From your comments it seems to me you need subquery with in

check this fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dfd72f991002af383465af763af290c3

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLENAME WHERE PRODUCT_ID = <yourID>)
```

I guess this is what you are looking for

As per your image (considering gtin is product ID)

your query should be

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
  WHERE receipt_header_id IN (SELECT receipt_header_id 
                              FROM TABLENAME 
                              WHERE gtin = <yourID>)
```

Comment: doesn't work, output is only the searched ProductID not the whole ID set

Comment: @DanielF This query and the one given by Zaynul Abadin Tuhin will give you the result set in your question based on the source data in your question.  If you are running this query against a different dataset then you really need to update your question to include what exactly it is that you're looking for.  If this is not giving you what you want then it's not at all clear what you mean by "all IDs, Product IDs and quantities".

Comment: @squillman check: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hkp5Sy2Y8VFaj86Ft3hFdZ/0 and what i need is told above "and my result set should look like this:"

Comment: @DanielF The query in your fiddle is not the same as the query in both answers.  Your fiddle says `WHERE ProductID IN...`.  Both answers correctly say `WHERE ID IN...`.  You also have ProductID in your subquery instead of ID.

Comment: @DanielF if the result set should look like what you have in your example why do you need joins? you have given your answer there :|

Comment: in the image is gtin the productID?